# How to set min and max replicas for deployment level?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

Can we set min and max limit for deployments at deployment level, not at cluster or replica set level in kubernetes ?

Comment: This setting here would be obvious: `kubectl explain deployment.spec.replicas`, but I suspect that is not what you mean.

Answer (score 7):

On deployment level **it is not possible**, but there is an option to do this indirectly. You should use a **HorizontalPodAutoscaler** (HPA for short):

> HPA automatically updates a workload resource (such as a Deployment or
> StatefulSet), with the aim of automatically scaling the workload to
> match demand.

Example code for HPA:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: php-apache
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: php-apache
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
```

More information can be found in [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/).

Answer (score 0):

At deployment level only replicas attribute is there.  When you define hpa there is an option for min and max